# Running Spark on heterogeneous cluster in standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark

I have a cluster of 3 nodes, each has 12 cores, and 30G, 20G and 10G of RAM respectively. When I run my application, I set the executor memory to 20G, which prevent the executor from being launched in the 10G machine since it's exceeding the slave memory threshold, it also under utilize the resources on the 30G machine. I searched but didn't find any way to set the executor memory dynamically base on the capacity of the node, so how can I config the cluster or my Spark job to fully utilize the resources of the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to have more executors with to less memory. You can use all of the memory by having 6- 10G executors (1 on the 10G node, 2 on the 20G node, 3 on the 30G node). Or by having 12- 5G executors. etc

Comment: But AFAIK the only way to config the number of executors in standalone mode is to set the `spark.executor.cores`, and this is a fixed value across all nodes, meaning the same value of this setting will be applied to all the machines in the cluster regardless of the cores they have, so if I set it to 3, I will end up with 12 / 3 = 4 executors on each machine, still use the same amount of memory collectively. Is there another way of setting the number of executors in standalone mode?

Comment: Ah, I missed your note that each node had 12 cores. In that case, you're either going to have unused memory or unused cores. Unfortunately, all Spark executors need to be identical.

Comment: I think you can pass the number of cores as argument to Spark submit.